# Proofing Heating Pipe Passage Way

Tags: heating, pipe, cover

I am living in a multi-family house which happens to be an old building. The person living under my room is a chain smoker. Unfortunately, the smoke is smellable in my room, even if I close the window and the doors. The only direct connection beween our flats is the heating pipe passage way.

Now the passage way was proofed with silicone. I wanted to renew the silicon because I thought this might help.

This is how it looked with silicone:
[image]

This is how it looks after removing it:
[image]

What is this stuff inside that looks like loose wool? Should I replace it with something before I put silicone on it? Any ideas how can improve the proofing so that almost no smoke will pass through?

Edit: Heres a requested picture of the floor:[image]

Comment: If the entire floor is wood and it is not 'wood flooring' but just the base with carpet or something over it - I am sure you have leaks in more than one place. and then I would recommend to lay a sheet of clear plastic over the entire floor and install flooring over that.

Comment: @Ken sorry I am not sure if I have understood you correctly. I added a picture of our floor how it looks in our entire flat (except kitchen and bathroom). I do not know whats under it. You may be right, there might be more leaks. But I can identify that the mayjor sorce of the smell must come from the pipeline. If we have fixed it, have I understood you correctly that you would recommend to put another layer like a carpet or fake wood?

Comment: Wow! Those are some gaps between the floor boards! And you say that you think the tobacco odor is coming in around the heating pipes?

Comment: @JimStewart Yes. If I go with my nose to the pipe it smells very bad. If I go with my nose anywhere else on the ground I do not smell much. The gaps are only about 7mm deep. Its not that I can view my neigbour through it :P

Comment: how do you know that the source of odor is the pipe? .... it could be the gap under the wall near the pipe

Comment: @jsotola I can not guarantee it. But if I smell on the wall on other sides of the room then I don't smell much. And after I have removed the silicon, it smells extremely heavily in this room.

Answer (score 1):

It will very hard to prevent the odor of tobacco smoke from getting into your flat. I would not attempt to renew with that seal, you could make it worse.
That wool could be anything from steel wool to copper wool to other fibers that you definitely don't want to do anything to. You don't want to disrupt it.

You could put some duct tape over the existing seal, but even that could cause problems. If any tape you placed there were later pulled off, it could pull apart the existing seal.

Comment: So you say I should just put silicon on it and leave the fibre alone? Do you have a recommendation which silicon I could use? I was thinking about something like this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Permatex-81160-High-Temperature-Red-Silicone-RTV-Gasket-Maker-3oz-Tube-/201267713058

Comment: You could smear a layer of silicone rubber over it, and the product you list should work.  Definitely DO NOT disrupt the fibre seal. Is this a rented flat?

Comment: Okay thanks. Yes its rented, but my grandmother is the owner of the flat.

Comment: What do you think about buying glass wool and putting on top of the existing fibre, and then making silicone on it?

Comment: Your grandmother is the owner of the flat you are in? There is already fibre there; I don't think you should add more. As far as the type of RTV silicone, it is hard to say which type would be better than others. "Gasket maker" might work or simple high temperature might be just as good for a little less money.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will just try it. Yes my grandmother bought this flat and is now in retirement home. Currently I can live there and only have to pay for housing subsidy. But it think I will have to move out because of the smokers below that flat :(.

Comment: Since your grandmother owns the flat you could ask her to put in plastic sheeting and a "click-in" floating floor that would not damage the existing flooring and would be easy to remove if that was wanted. I could imagine any non-smoking occupants being unhappy with the smoke from below.

Comment: Yes I am also thinking about it and I think Ken also suggested in in the comments. Even if I pay for myself its cheaper then moving. But I thing that the main source comes from the heating pipe, because its smells super strong at right this point.So I am afraid if this is not going to be fixed, then a plastic sheeting and "click-in" won't help either.

Comment: Get the RTV silicone and smear it on!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to lay some form of seal all the way across that floor - the smoke is simply coming through the flooring - the gaps in those boards etc.. you have pretty much the same air. You might lay a painters mil clear mat over the entire floor (seal around the ends ) and then put a carpet on top of that .. Much like a lid on a jar.

The only other solution is to move to a better place.